# Javascript Error: qGrid is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have this error in Javascript saying "qGrid is not defined" and it points to this line

```
$page=$('#stfLeafFacetsGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam','page');
```

I am totally new to javascript, but this line looks very correct to me. So I am not sure where could the problem be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$page=$('#stfLeafFacetsGrid').qGrid('getGridParam','page');
```

Perhaps?

Comment: now it says "Error: $("#stfLeafFacetsGrid").qGrid is not a function"

Comment: aye, mine's a stab really - Oleg's right, load your dependencies in a controlled order, and you'll get more consistency and less heartache. At the very least listen to window load and dom ready events, if you aren't already.

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of errors one has typically with the wrong order of loading of the JavaScript files. For example one have to load i18n/grid.locale-en.js **before** jquery.jqGrid.min.js (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid#html_file)).

If you has another problem you should include full HTML and JavaScript code in your question.